# How to get time difference from current time to given time in munite

Tags: php

I want to get time difference between my given time from current Times calculate from UNIX format.

my code is not giving me the right answer.

**My PHP code:**

```
$my_time = 1407410382;
$time_diff = strtotime(strftime("%F") . ' ' .$my_time) - time();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$then = 1407410382;

//Get the current timestamp.
$now = time();

//Calculate the difference.
$difference = $now - $then;

//Convert seconds into minutes.
$minutes = floor($difference / 60);

echo $minutes;
```